# How to display "<" in xml value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml-file and a tag (`MyText`) as a value inside another element tag
Like this:

```
<header>
   <subheader>
      <somethingelse>
          A text ...
          ... like this list<MyText> is an example!
          ...
          of my xml-file.
      </somethingelse>
   </subheader>
</header>
```

Now I get an error

The `MyText` start tag on line 159 position 14 does not match the end tag of 'somethingelse'. Line 204, position 9.

...and...

Line 334:

```
var myDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(dir_AppData + "Examples.xml"));
```

How do you do that ?

Comment: see: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Comment: `<` is a special character in XML.  Either use `&lt;` or wrap the content of the element in a CDATA block.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will use CDATA.

Comment: That's not an XML file....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
&lt;
```

Or declare a CDATA section in your XML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Answer (score 3):

Escape them with  `&lt;` (**L**esser **t**hen) for < and `&gt;` (**G**reater **t**hen) for >

Answer (score 1):

To include such a special character you have to use this character reference : `&#60;` or `&lt`

You have a whole list there :
http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to solve your problem:

1. The first one use CDATA tag .

   *For more information visit w3school:* http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp
2. The second option is use Xml Entities to escape special characterizes

   *for more information about escape chars*: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Enclose values in  tags, or use escape sequences

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp